# What is this in MVC5, an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It is common to see extra values or attributes passed into things like

`@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`

What is the `new {...}` part called? Is it an object? It doesn't seem like an object because new object {...} will cause errors.

I use this a lot, but I don't actually have that deep of an understanding of what the `new {...}` syntax is dong.

Comment: Absolutely everything in C# is an `object`, so technically, yes, it is. Besides that point, you are actually creating an anonymous object in your example.

Answer (score 3):

It's an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397696.aspx) object - a feature of C# rather than MVC5. The compiler creates an anonymous type with read-only properties, matching the names and types used in the initalizer. At runtime an instance of this type is created and MVC iterates over its properties using reflection.

Comment: It's worth noting that in that specific case it's an anonymous object, however, you can also instantiate defined objects using the same syntax.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath You can? Can you post a example or link to how? The closest I can think of is array instantiation via `new[] { ... }`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I referred specifically to array instantiation :) there might be some other case though

Comment: But that is not "the same syntax" `new {...}` and `new[] {...}` are two ***very*** different syntaxes in my opinion.

Comment: That isn't the same syntax or even the question they are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Adding more information here, Anonymous types are the types created using new keyword and some readonly properties.

```
var AnonType =  new {propertyName1  = "property", propertyName2 = "Prop"};
```

Datatype of the properties are decided based on the data you insert, for example if you assign int to the property it becomes integer and so on. These are readonly properties so you an not change the value of them.

[image]

in your case ValidationSummary is an extension method on HtmlHelper Class, and takes various overloads. Here htmlAttribute is one of the parameter of type object(Anonymous). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's an anonymous object.

See here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Please edit your answer and add some information from the post

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I think it is a full answer. If all links where dead it still 100% answers the question. The link just provides supplmental information.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I don't agree with you. Not every single `new { ... } ` creates an anonymous object. At best is a partial answer

Comment: the other answer is the same as mine. yet you only down voted this one?

Comment: and every new that isn't declared with a type is an anonymous object.